# How to create relate one table with others using Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
    User TABLE:
    id -> int
    email -> varchar
```

```
    Tag TABLE:
    id -> int
    name -> varchar
```

```
    tags_user TABLE
    tab_id ->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tag');
    user_id ->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('user');
```

how to get all tags from specific user?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need many to many relationship:

**In your user model:**

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag');
    }

}
```

**In your Tag model:**

```
class Tag extends Eloquent {

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }

}
```

**Then from your controller:**
Utilize the many to many relationship.

```
$tags = User::find(1)->tags;
```

**Important:**

Three database tables are needed for this relationship: `users`, `tags`, and `tag_user`. The `tag_user` table is derived from the alphabetical order of the related model names, and should have `user_id` and `tag_id` columns.

Reference:

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many

Comment: I believe tag_user is correct, other than that, good summary.

Comment: Thanks to catch that.